# ReferenceError: 'Activity' is undefined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

code:

```
H.Binder.TaskColor = function ($elem, role, value, data) {
            this.element = $elem;
            this.value = value;
            this.data = data.Activity;
            this.init = function () {
                var ProgressPercent = this.data.ProgressPercent;
                if (ProgressPercent < 50)
                    this.element.addClass("style1");

                else
                    this.element.addClass("style2");
            }
            this.refresh = function () {
                this.init();
            }
        }
```

html:

```
TaskItemTemplate="<div class='rq-gc-taskbar' data-bind='TaskColor: Activity.ProgressPercent' ><div class='rq-gc-taskbar-label'></div></div>"
```

Error:

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings.

Message: ReferenceError: 'Activity' is undefined;

Bindings value: TaskColor: Activity.ProgressPercent

Comment: What is 'data'? And where is the code that set it?

Comment: I feel like there's some important code missing here. Could you share the whole file? Particularly where the H.Binder.TaskColor function is called and wherever a var called "Activity" shows up. This is definitely a scoping issue, just need to figure out where the scope is getting messed up.

Comment: Have you checked if you are passing `Activity` in data?

Comment: Check the value of data in quick watch and see if it really contains Activity object or not.

Comment: the function is receiving any value, it's not going inside function itself.